# Intra-rater reliability of an instrument

Tags: paired-data, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation, bland-altman-plot

I'm working on the implementation of a "new version" of an existing instrument in the posture analysis.
I know that if I want to compare the measures between the old one and the new one I can use Bland-Altman plot, but what I'm trying to do is assess the reliability of this instrument by comparing the measures collected twice.
I mean, something like the intra-rater. Do you think is correct to use this approach since I'm evaluating the outcomes of the instrument and not the rater?

Comment: Are you trying to measure [repeatability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) aka test-retest reliability?

Comment: Almost yes, but this should be not "test-retest" since it is applied only for questionnaires rather than instruments, right?

Comment: "reliability of instrument by comparing the measures collected twice" sounds like test-retest.

Comment: Seaching through internet it does not refer to instruments. But if you are sure I'll go for it

Comment: As I said, can't do testRetest because I'm not evaluating the outcomes of a test (eg likert scale) but measurements.